# How to group array elements and get many occurring elements?

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio

How to get an element of an array that occur multiple times?

```
ArrayList<String> arrBarCode = new ArrayList<String>();
arrBarCode.add(BarCode);
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking about. Do you mean how to get the frequency of a certain barcode in the list, e.g. something like `Map<String, Integer>`? If so, what did you try so far?

Comment: do you wanna get single element as unique ?

Comment: Yes, right. I want to get the frequency of a particular barcode in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Map<String, Integer>` to remember the number of occurrences while iterating over the `List`:

```
ArrayList<String> arrBarCode = new ArrayList<String>();
arrBarCode.add("a");
arrBarCode.add("a");
arrBarCode.add("a");
arrBarCode.add("c");
Map<String, Integer> a = new HashMap<>();
arrBarCode.forEach(s -> a.put(s, a.computeIfAbsent(s, foo -> 0)+1));
System.out.println(a);
```

prints

```
{a=3, c=1}
```